# Meaning of 'it is' in '...than it is that ...'

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

> [[Source]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams#Boston_Massacre) He also offered a now-famous, detailed defense of [Blackstone's
> Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackstone%27s_Ratio):
> "*It is
> more important* that innocence be protected than **it is** that guilt be
> punished, for guilt and crimes are so frequent in this world that they
> cannot all be punished..

I first guessed that the bolded (which figures in a comparative clause) implies an ellipsis of *'it is more important'*, already stated in the main clause. Yet I doubt this guess, because 2 below seems inane?

> 1. *It is
> more important* that innocence be protected than **it is [more important]** that guilt be
> punished...
>
> 2. = [Protection of] innocence is **more important** than punishment of guilt is **more important**.

So what's the antecedent of **it**? Is it a dummy pronoun? Even if so, what legitimates this use of **it is**, which mystifies me? What are its purposes? Are there any formal terms describing these issues?

Comment: As you suggested initially, **it** is a dummy subject and refers forward to the **that-noun clause**.

Answer (score 2):

*It* is here the dummy subject *it*.

The dummy subject *it* allows the writer to avoid a lengthy subject that is itself a clause, and therefore relatively difficult to process for the reader.

This use also highlights the phrase *more important,* making clear that the sender wants to compare.

Finally, using *it* here simply alerts the receiver that complex information follows.

Without the dummy subject, we might have:

> That innocence should be protected is more important than that guilt should be punished, because . . . .

Thus, the dummy subject refers to *that innocence should be protected.*

*More important* receives extra attention because it is a complement and it is the first piece of information that appears in the sentence that is not essentially empty of meaning. This informs the receiver that the sender wants to make a comparison.

All of the information about guilt, how it's less important, and why, receives extra attention as it occupies the end position of the main clause and of the sentence as a whole.

All of the information about guilt, which is complex, is easier to process because it has been shifted to the end.